# Pull row with lowest number in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have two columns called topic_id and post_id, and what I want to do is find every row where the topic_id is the lowest for each post ID.

For example
topic_id post_id
1 5
2 5
3 8
4 8

So it would grab row 1 and 3.

I am not even sure where to begin so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
select post_id, min(topic_id)
    from YourTable
    group by post_id
```

Comment: TFGITW means?? is it `Too Fast Guy In The World`!

Comment: @diEcho: "The Fastest Gun in the West".

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be able to do something like

```
SELECT      MIN(`topic_id`), `post_id`
FROM        `my_table`
GROUP BY    `post_id`
```

Take a look [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN(topic_id), post_id
FROM   T
GROUP BY post_id
```

Answer (score 0):

select topic_id, min(post_id) from  where  group by topic_id